# Finding out maxThreads set by JBOSS EAP

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I know we can set maxThreads in HTTP Connectors to increase the no of HTTP connections.

Also read that the default value is set computing as below

this.maxThreads = (org.apache.tomcat.util.Constants.LOW_MEMORY ? 64 : 512 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

How would i be able to see/get the value set in JBOSS from above?
I managed executing the above code in standalone JAVA class, but would like to know the set value in JBOSS?